# Looking for a Complex Analysis textbook that introduces the extended complex number system $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ early on.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

All the textbooks that I've encountered on the subject of measure theory make use of the extended real number system $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ right from the start. The theory is developed with respect to this number system.

This is in contrast to the textbooks on the subject of Complex Analysis that I have encountered so far, which develop a substantial part of the theory with respect to the complex number system $\mathbb{C}$, and only later introduce the extended complex number system $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$. These books then write something to the effect of: "All the results we have seen so far apply, with appropriate adjustments, to the extended complex number system."

I'm looking for introductory textbooks about Complex Analysis (introductory in the sense that they're not specialized to selected advanced topics, but build the theory from the ground up) that either introduce the extended complex number system in the beginning, rather than as an afterthought, and build the theory on top of it, or else when they do eventually introduce the extended complex number system, they explicitly restate all those results seen so far that require a restatement when $\mathbb{C}$ is replaced by the extended complex number system.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between the real $\infty$ and the complex one. In real analysis, $\pm \infty$ are mostly just formal symbols, while in the complex case, $\infty$ is a genuine point (on the Riemann sphere).

Comment: Real analysis and complex analysis are two different worlds, thus not directly comparable. There isn't much similarity between the two, contrast to what their names suggest.

Comment: "Introductory Complex Analysis" by Richard Silverman covers the extended complex plane early in the text and uses it throughout.

Comment: @Justauser This is not true. For example, all the measure theory textbooks I know define random variables as potentially assuming the value $\infty$, and consider it an integral part of the real number system with associated laws of algebra.

Comment: @EvanAad To have any meaning result, the probability is 0, and hence can be replaced by any other place holder.

Comment: Foundations of Complex Analysis by S Ponnusamy is an excellent book containing numerous problems with hints for solutions, on the various topics in Complex Analysis. The variety of problems in the exercises is really astounding. The author is from IIT Madras.

Comment: The main difference between $\mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ and $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ is that the latter is given structure of a Riemann surface with two charts: the ordinary chart $\mathbb C$ and the chart at $\infty$ is $(\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}) - \{0\}$. The overlap map between the two charts is the map $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$. This allows one to extend much of the ordinary theory of complex analysis, i.e. homolorphic functions, analytic functions, etc., to $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: However, there's a heavy load of baggage that goes along with discussing Riemann surfaces, atlases, overlap maps, etc. That baggage is a distraction from the ordinary theory of holomorphic functions, analyticity and Taylor series representations, etc. This might explain somewhat why it's hard to find such books.